CSS & HTML heading getting misplaced on webpage
Unlike <h2>Personal information<h2> which shows perfectly how I want it to show the <h2>Emergency contact<h2> header that gets misplaced on the page.
The CSS for <h2> is on the CSS folder below:
<section class="personal-info">
                <h2>PERSONAL INFORMATION</h2>
                <form>

                    @*get firstname and last name to alighn with the other textboxes also make them fill the page*@

                    <label for="FirstName">First Name</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control", id = "FirstName", placeholder = "Enter First Name" })

                    <div class="form-row col-lg-10">
                        <label for="LastName">Last Name</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LastName, new { @class = "form-control", id = "LastName", placeholder = "Enter Last Name" })
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="ID_Number">ID Number</label>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ID_Number, new { @class = "form-control", id = "ID_Number", placeholder = "Enter ID Number" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="DateOfBirth">Date Of Birth</label>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.DateOfBirth, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control datepicker", id = "DateOfBirth", placeholder = "DD/MM/YYYY" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="dllGetGender">Gender</label>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.GenderIDFK, new List<SelectListItem>(), "Select Gender", new { @class = "form-control", id = "dllGetGender" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="dllPhoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PhoneNumber, new { @class = "form-control", id = "dllPhoneNumber", placeholder = "Enter Phone Number" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="dllEmail">Email</label>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email, new { @class = "form-control", id = "dllEmail", placeholder = "Enter Email" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="dllLine1">Address Line 1</label>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Line1, new { @class = "form-control", id = "dllLine1", placeholder = "Enter Address Line 1" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="dllLine2">Address Line 2</label>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Line2, new { @class = "form-control", id = "dllLine2", placeholder = "Enter Address Line 2" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="dllGetCities">City</label>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CityIDFK, new List<SelectListItem>(), "Select City", new { @class = "form-control", id = "dllGetCities" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="dllGetProvinces">Province</label>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ProvinceIDFK, new List<SelectListItem>(), "Select Province", new { @class = "form-control", id = "dllGetProvinces" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="dllGetCountries">Country</label>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CountryIDFK, new List<SelectListItem>(), "Select Country", new { @class = "form-control", id = "dllGetCountries" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </section>
            
            <hr />
            <section class="emergancy-contact">
                @*get h2 to give only they emergancy contact color *@
                <h2>emergancy contact</h2>
                <form>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="dllGetMaritalStatus">Marital Status</label>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.MaritalStatusIDFK, new List<SelectListItem>(), "Select Marital Status", new { @class = "form-control", id = "dllGetMaritalStatus" })
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="dllEmergencyName">Emergency Name</label>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EmergencyName, new { @class = "form-control", id = "dllEmergencyName", placeholder
= "Enter Emergency Contact Name" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="dllEmergencyLastName">Emergency Last Name</label>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EmergencyLastName, new { @class = "form-control", id = "dllEmergencyLastName", placeholder = "Enter Emergency Contact Last Name" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="dllEmergencyPhoneNumber">Emergency Phone Number</label>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EmergencyPhoneNumber, new { @class = "form-control", id = "dllEmergencyPhoneNumber", placeholder = "Enter Emergency Contact Phone" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="dllRelationship">Relationship</label>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Relationship, new { @class = "form-control", id = "dllRelationship", placeholder = "Enter Relationship" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="dllEmergancyDateOfBirth">Emergency Contact DOB</label>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EmergancyDateOfBirth, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control datepicker", id = "dllEmergancyDateOfBirth", placeholder = "DD/MM/YYYY" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </section>

The following is the CSS code:
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.form-container {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 30px auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

header {
    background-color: #00796b;
    padding: 20px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.header-content {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.logo img {
    width: 100px;
}

.title h1 {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
}

h2 {
    background-color: #004d40;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

form {
    margin: 20px 0;
}

label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

input, select, textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

    input[type="radio"] {
        width: auto;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }

textarea {
    height: 100px;
}

footer {
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

    footer p {
        font-weight: bold;
    }

address {
    font-style: normal;
}

.signature p {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-style: italic;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

This is the page:

In order to solve this you need to arrive at the minimal amount of code which replicates the problem. Take a copy of your page, then keep removing things from it until the problem no longer occurs. Then can add back the piece you removed most recently and confirm that the problem recurs.

In order to solve this we are going to need a runnable snippet. Here is a runnable snippet I derived from your template code, but it doesn't seem to replicate the problem. I suggest that you copy this snippet into your post and then edit it until it replicates the problem.


body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  margin: 1em;
}

.form-container {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 30px auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

header {
  background-color: #00796b;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.header-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo img {
  width: 100px;
}

.title h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
}

h2 {
  background-color: #004d40;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

form {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

input, select, textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  width: auto;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

textarea {
  height: 100px;
}

footer {
  margin-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

footer p {
  font-weight: bold;
}

address {
  font-style: normal;
}

.signature p {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: italic;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="personal-info">
  <h2>PERSONAL INFORMATION</h2>
  <form>

    <label for="FirstName">First Name</label>
    <input id="FirstName" type="text">
    
    <div class="form-row col-lg-10">
      <label for="LastName">Last Name</label>
      <input id="LastName" type="text">
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="ID_Number">ID Number</label>
        <input id="ID_Number" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="DateOfBirth">Date Of Birth</label>
        <input id="DateOfBirth" type="date">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="dllGetGender">Gender</label>
        <select id="dllGetGender"></select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="dllPhoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
        <input id="dllPhoneNumber" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</section>

<hr>

<section class="emergency-contact">
  <h2>emergency contact</h2>
  <form>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="dllGetMaritalStatus">Marital Status</label>
        <select id="dllGetGender"></select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="dllEmergencyName">Emergency Name</label>
        <input id="dllEmergencyName" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="dllEmergencyLastName">Emergency Last Name</label>
        <input id="dllEmergencyLastName" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="dllEmergencyPhoneNumber">Emergency Phone Number</label>
        <input id="dllEmergencyPhoneNumber" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="dllRelationship">Relationship</label>
        <input id="dllEmergencyPhoneNumber" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="dllEmergancyDateOfBirth">Emergency Contact DOB</label>
        <input id="dllEmergancyDateOfBirth" type="date">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</section>




so what i've found is when i remove col-md-6 from the above form-groups it adjusts to just having color on EMERGENCY CONTACT but when i add any colonel it gets misplaced

Try to change this
<div class="form-row col-lg-10">

to this:
<div class="form-row col-lg-12">

col-lg-10 leaves some space (2 columns in the 12 column system) on the rigth side, to which the first word of the second h2 apparently "slips up". Filling the complete space (using col-lg-12) might fix that.

Unfortunately this didn't work it still gives me the same problem

so what i've found is when i remove col-md-6 from the above form-groups it adjusts to just having color on EMERGENCY CONTACT but when i add any colonel it gets misplaced
